# Relative clauses: extra information clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

[image]

Hello.

I can't understand how some of the relative clauses work in English. I see no difference between the two given examples:

> Barbara works for a company...
>
> Colin told me about his new job...

*a company/new job*

What's the difference? Why can't we use **that** in the second sentence? I think they **both** give some **extra** information, not just the second one. But they say we can use **which** in the first one. If so, why don't they put a comma before it?

All the explanations I read on the topic are not clear and do not tell the difference.

There's another sentence **that/which (???)** I found on the web:

> The iPad (which/that) connects to the iCloud was created by Apple.
>
> The correct answer is: The iPad, which connects to the iCloud, was
> created by Apple. (All iPads connect to the iCloud, so it's
> unnecessary information.)

If we use **that**, does it mean there are other iPads **that/which (???)** were created by other companies (but we know that all iPads are made by Apple — there's only one iPad **that/which (???)** is created by Apple)?

This is so confusing. I also put **that/which** clauses in bold that I don't know the correct answer for (I hope some of them are interchangeable).

Please help!

Comment: In Type 1, the relative clause helps to identify the thing being spoken of ('a company which makes washing machines'). In Type 2, the clause is just a comment about the thing ('his job, which he is enjoying').

Comment: Hello, Kate. Thank you for your reply!
In type 1, how do I know it's not a comment about the thing (especially if we can use **which** there as well)? I mean, how do I tell the difference between a comment and an 'identifier'?

Comment: I don't know how I can explain it any more clearly than your book does. There are many companies, but not so many that make washing machines, so it is information that identifies the one that Barbara works for.

Comment: If you use *that* in the second sentence, it changes the meaning: now Colin has more than one new job. *Colin told me about his new job that he's enjoying very much. [He didn't tell me anything about his other new job.]* In the first sentence — *Barbara works for a company that makes washing machines* — *which* would not be used — at least according to many or most style guides (especially in American English).

Answer (score 1):

*That vs Which* is an interesting piece of grammar, **which** is probably on a par with *Who vs Whom* in the popularity stakes. That being said, let's cut to the chase.

First note that one of the potentially confusing things about the extract you've provided is that it doesn't seem to explicitly mention that you could use *that* and *which* interchangeably where *that* can be used. But the same does not apply to *which.*

Now the main part: You use *which* in the case of nonrestrictive/non-defining relative clauses. In other words, relative clauses **that** provide extra information (you could do away with this information without rendering the sentence meaningless) about the *subject* are introduced by *which* and set off by commas from the essential part of the sentence. The commas sort of mark a boundary between the essential and the parenthetical parts of the sentence. This is why in the sentence *Colin told me about his new job, which he's enjoying very much*, the relative clause is introduced by *which* because the clause is merely providing extra information and could be easily removed from the sentence without affecting it. Compare this with *Barbara works for a company that makes washing machines*: here the restrictive clause *that makes washing machines* precisely defines the company Barbara works for and isn't merely providing extra information about the company, unlike the "Colin" example. Thus no commas here. As mentioned earlier, you could also use *which* in the Barbara example but *sans commas* (because it is a restrictive clause still.)

After reading this, I'm pretty sure that the iPad example should be easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I start to comprehend it much better. I probably have to look out for more examples and do some grammar exercises on the topic.

When I was describing the iPad example, I used that/which a lot, but I'm not sure about the correct choices. I would choose **that** for every single case (not the quoted example, but my thoughts around it). I don't think they are interchangeable there as well. Am I correct?

Comment: Since from the example it follows that all iPads connect to the iCloud, _which_ is warranted. If only a select class of iPads connected to the iCloud, you would be defining that select class, warranting _that_ ("without commas" clause).

Comment: Compare these: _The horses, which were in the stable, have died._; _The horses that were in the barn have died._ Both are correct sentences but they mean different things.

Comment: I think I got it... *The horses, which were in the stable, have died* means all the horses have died. *The horses that were in the barn have died* means only those in the barn have died. Then, *The horses that were in the stable have died* would mean only the horses that were in the stable have died. And *The horses, which were in the barn, have died* would mean all the horses have died.

Comment: I suppose this is correct. Not quite sure, though. I'm sorry for asking you this, but can you correct the mistakes, please? — There's another sentence **that** (not **which**) I found on the web... If we use that, does it mean there are other iPads **that** (not **which**) were created by other companies (but we know that all iPads are made by Apple — there's only one iPad **which** (not **that**) is created by Apple)?

Comment: Please go over the examples again. You'll find it out. :)

Comment: _My grandson who is an attorney lives in Virginia._; _My grandson, who is an attorney, lives in Virginia._ The first sentence means that I've many grandsons and I'm identifying **one** of them (the one who's an attorney living in Virginia.); the second sentence me and that I've **only one** grandson and the parenthetical clause is merely providing extra information about him.

Comment: It is misleading to say "You use _which_ in the case of nonrestrictive/non-defining relative clauses". Both "that" and "which" can occur in restrictive clauses, and most often they are interchangeable.

Comment: @BillJ: From my answer above _First note that one of the potentially confusing things about the extract you've provided is that it doesn't seem to explicitly mention that you could use "that" and "which" interchangeably where "that" can be used. But the same does not apply to "which"._ I think we're on the same page on this, right?

Comment: The fact remains that your statement "You use which in the case of nonrestrictive/non-defining relative clauses" is misleading. In fact your entire answer is confused and misleading.

Comment: I would you grateful if you provide an enlightening answer then, @BillJ :)

Comment: By the way, you kind of make it look like there's no difference at all between the two— further necessitating an authoritative answer.

Comment: @user405662 Excuse me, did I get the horse sentences wrong?

Comment: @user405662 and those Apple sentences featuring *that* and *which*, could you please correct me if I'm wrong there? The topic itself becomes more clear though.

Comment: @Araucaria- Not here any more: I've deleted it! :)

Comment: You here?! @Araucaria :D

Comment: @Araucaria- Not here any more: Yes. I deleted it later thinking it wasn't the right place to be asking off-topic questions. :)

Comment: @user178049 Only ephemerally!

Comment: @User40475 Well, we can delete these comments in a bit. The answer to your Q is that I had no problem with linguistics at all, but had a terrible 'working' relationship with an awful supervisor. I transferred to a brilliant supervisor at a different university, and all is good!

Comment: @Araucaria- Not here any more Good to know that you're continuing with it. Just a small request: Please suggest some really good books on linguistics (not the overly-technical type). I mean books that provide a comprehensive picture of what linguistics is all about as well as a sound working knowledge of the same. Will remove the comments shortly thereafter. Also, it interests me as to what kind of books you read in fiction/nonfiction? I wonder if linguisticians are rather choosy about the type of books they read. I hope you reply. :)

Comment: So, don't want you to think I'm not going to reply. In terms of quite general, but nonetheless interesting reads, there's two books by David Crystal: *The Encyclopedia of Language* and *How language works*. The latter won't teach you an awful lot about formal linguistics, but may tell you which area of linguistics you might find the most interesting/exciting. The former's properly linguistic. I'll put my thinking cap on for more useful books in terms of  'a sound working knowledge'. It depends, very heavily, of course, on what areas of linguistics you want to know about!

Comment: Thank you very much, @Araucaria- Not here any more.